# No php.ini found in public_html

Tags: php

What should I do if there is no "`php.ini`" in my "`public_html`" folder? If I have to create it, how can I do so?

Comment: You should keep your `php.ini` out of your web root, if possible.

Comment: @alex And how can I create it ?

Comment: `What should I do if there is no php.in in my public_html folder?`  - nothing. There's no need to create individual php.inis, one central one will do. What is your situation, why are you asking this?

Comment: It's just a text file. The bigger issue will be whether your host allows you to have a custom one.

Comment: The per-directory configuration for PHP is done either via `.htaccess`or `.user.ini` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`php.ini`" file does not reside in the web server's "`public_html`" directory. This directory is meant for publicly viewable files & folders. It's a very bad idea to use the "php.ini" file.

Instead use [HTAccess](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php) or use the PHP function "[`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)" for making changes in your website's PHP Configurations.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't know about `ini_set()` Should I place it in every php file ?

Comment: You can create a main file "`_config.php`", which can contain all the changes of PHP Configurations using the function "`ini_set()`". And make this main config file "`_config.php`" included in each PHP file using PHP function "`include_once()`" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), just at line #2 (approximately, where line #1 will contain the PHP start tag "`<?php`").